# Auto scaling for Google container engine

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

Can GKE (Google Container Engine) do autoscaling?  I know that it allows manual adjustment of node replication, but can it be configured some how to detect load and replicate automatically?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Updating my answer as Kubernetes now has this feature.

Kubernetes now supports horizontal scaling of Pods - http://kubernetes.io/v1.1/docs/user-guide/horizontal-pod-autoscaler.html

If you mean autoscaling of the nodes in GCE rather than the pods running inside it, then yes it can - you can turn on autoscaling for a managed instance group such as GCE - see the docs below but the short version is just edit the instance group to enable autoscaling.

https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/autoscaler/

Comment: I meant the containers inside the pods.

Comment: in that case, no it's not possible (yet) though you can manually make a kubectl resize if you want.

Comment: Autoscaling is something that is actively being worked on - you can read more here https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/docs/proposals/autoscaling.md

Comment: FYI Horizontal Pod Autoscaler is now in Kubernetes v1.1: http://kubernetes.io/v1.1/docs/user-guide/horizontal-pod-autoscaler.html

Comment: Thanks James - I've updated this answer to reflect this.

Comment: All these links are 404.